# Как получить Public ECDSA Key из Private ECDSA Key на Java

Tags: java, android, криптография

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить  Public ECDSA Key из Private ECDSA Key на Java Android. Использую [org.bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories)

Для проверки использую этот ресурс http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address
Например ввожу Private ECDSA Key

> 18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725

Должен получить

> 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме приватного ключа должно быть известно имя эллиптической кривой, которая использовалась. Так как в вашем примере есть ответ для проверки, то можно вычислить, что использовалась кривая `secp256k1`:

```
private static X9ECParameters curve = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName("secp256k1");
private static ECDomainParameters domain = new ECDomainParameters(
        curve.getCurve(), curve.getG(), curve.getN(), curve.getH());

public static byte[] toPublicKey(byte[] privateKey) {
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger(privateKey);
    ECPoint q = domain.getG().multiply(d);

    ECPublicKeyParameters publicParams = new ECPublicKeyParameters(q, domain);
    return publicParams.getQ().getEncoded(false);
}
```